# Making an HTML page to display n rows of pascal's triangle, cannot array.push the current row to page

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to JavaScript, and decided to do some practice with displaying n rows of Pascal's triangle. I have everything working, and the rows are displayed in the console, however when I try to push the currentRow to the array of triangle, nothing shows up on the page. Here is how I am attempting to do so:

```
    if (typeof currentRow !== 'undefined') {
        console.log('Row ', i - 2);
        currentRow = currentRow.join('  ');
        console.log(currentRow);
        console.log(triangle);
        triangle.push('n', currentRow)
        triangle = triangle.join('');
    }
```

Any help/advice would be apreciated. I am sure this code is not that efficient (I know it is not optimal to just write out the first 3 rows). Below is a code snippet, and a jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/keuo8za0/

```js
var row0 = [1];
var row1 = [1, 1];
var row2 = [1, 2, 1];
row0 = row0.join(' ');
row1 = row1.join(' ');
row2 = row2.join(' ');
var triangle = [row0];
triangle.push('\n', row1);
triangle.push('\n', row2);
triangle = triangle.join('');
lastRow = [1, 2, 1];
var submit = document.getElementById('submit');

function buildTriangle(pascalNumber) {
  for (let i = 4; i < pascalNumber; i++) {
    if (typeof currentRow !== 'undefined') {
        console.log('Row ', i - 2);
        currentRow = currentRow.join('  ');
        console.log(currentRow);
        console.log(triangle);
    }
    var x = i;
    var currentRow = [1, 1];
    for (let y = 1; y + 1 < x; y++) {
      var nextNumber = (lastRow[y - 1] + lastRow[y]);
      currentRow.splice(1, 0, nextNumber);
    }
    lastRow = currentRow;
  }
}

function drawTriangle() {
  document.getElementById('triangle').innerText = triangle;
}

submit.onclick = function() {
  var rownum = document.getElementById('pn').value;
  buildTriangle(rownum - 1);
  drawTriangle();
  return false;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #4286f4;
  font-family: arial;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: center;
}

h1:hover {
  color: #ff35c5;
}

form {
  font: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  font-size: 36px;
  font: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

#map {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Pascal's Triangle</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancy.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Pascal's Triangle</h1>
    <form id='numberOfRows'>
      Number of Rows:<br>
      <input id='pn' type='number'><br>
      <button id='submit'>Submit</button>
    </form>
    <p id='triangle'></p>
    <script src="triangler.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: At the point of the if statement to check if currentRow is undefined, from what it looks like that variable isn't ever defined when it's at that point

Answer (score 0):

Interesting... I did it row by row. Found really good help from google..

```
     <style>
        body {
          background: #4286f4;
          font-family: arial;
        }

        h1 {
          font-size: 36px;
          text-align: center;
        }

        h1:hover {
          color: #ff35c5;
        }

        form {
          font: sans-serif;
          text-align: center;
        }

        p {
          font-size: 36px;
          font: sans-serif;
          text-align: center;
        }

        #map {
          margin: 0 auto;
          width: 80%;
          height: 80%;
        }
     </style>

<h1>Pascal's Triangle</h1>
<form id='numberOfRows'>
  Number of Rows:<br>
  <input id='pn' type='number'><br>
  <button id='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
<p id='triangle'></p>


    <script>

    var div = document.getElementById('triangle');

    submit.onclick = function() {
      div.innerHTML = "";  
      var rownum = document.getElementById('pn').value;
      printPascal(rownum);
      return false;
    };

    function printPascal(n) {
        // Iterate through every line and 
        // print entries in it             
        for (var line=0; line < n; line++) 
        { 
            var lineHTML = "<div class='text-center'>";
            // Every line has number of 
            // integers equal to line 
            // number 
            for (var i = 0; i <= line; i++) {
                lineHTML += "" + binomialCoeff(line, i) + " &nbsp; &nbsp; ";     
            }
            lineHTML += "</div>\n";
            div.innerHTML += lineHTML;        
        }            

    }

    // for details of this function 
    function binomialCoeff(n, k) 
    { 
            var res = 1; 
            if (k > n - k) 
            k = n - k; 
            for (var i = 0; i < k; ++i) 
            { 
                    res *= (n - i); 
                    res /= (i + 1); 
            } 
    return res; 
    }         

    </script>
```